# Why am I connecting securely to MySQL when I don't have client certificates?

Tags: mariadb-10.2

I don't understand the MySQL documentation for encrypted connections. The server is configured with certificates, and unless I am misreading it, the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-encrypted-connections.html#using-encrypted-connections-client-side-configuration) says that the client must have certificates as well.

But, if I start the client with 'mysql --ssl' then \s reports that the connection is SSL encrypted using DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 even though I haven't used any certificates with the client. /etc/my.cnf.d/client.cnf does not have any certificates in the [client] section, and I don't have a .my.cnf

How is that possible that I am connected with SSL? Is it not really encrypted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes the connection is encrypted. I think you are getting a few things mixed up here. Let me try to simplify it for you:

[SSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) is a protocol for exchanging data across a secure network, and in order to establish a connection, the server must have a certificate to use. In order to obtain a certificate you must be issued one. This is generally done by a [Certificate Authority (CA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) or by using a [self-signed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate) one, but we will keep it simple here and stick with CA's.

If the certificate you used when setting up SSL is valid, and is ***trusted*** by the client attempting to establish a connection, then the connection attempt should succeed. The client does not need to present a certificate here, but it does need to trust the issuer of the certificate. This is generally done by having a copy of the CA certificate on your machine and verifying that the certificate presented by the server is signed/issued by the CA.This corresponds roughly to the `--ssl-mode=VERIFY_CA` and `--ssl-mode=VERIFY_IDENTITY` (which checks that the host name in the certificate matches the server you are trying to connect to).

MySQL allows the client to select the certificate to use when verifying the identity of the server using the `--ssl-ca`, `--ssl-cert` and `--ssl-key` options and in order for the transport connection to be successful, the certificate presented by the client must be issued by the same CA that issued the server certificate. This is optional, and if you don't present one then the client will look for a corresponding certificate in its store.

Additionally, once you have established an SSL connection you can authenticate an account using certificates (generally using some kind of [PKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure) technology) which would essentially replace using passwords to log in - but the key thing to understand here is that by the time the process gets to the point where you are attempting to log in, the SSL connection has already been established. When you use this method, you generally find that the client certificates have been issued by the same CA as the one that issued the server certificate.

I use the following analogy to explain it to people I teach:

> When my daughter was born the only people she knew she could trust was her mother and me. Then as she got older and more people came into her life we told her who she could and couldn't trust. In this scenario, my wife and I act as the Certificate Authority verifying the trustworthiness of others. If we have not told our daughter she can trust someone then she will not speak to them, much like a how a client will act if it does not trust a server.

The topic of certificates is quite extensive but the key for you is to understand the difference between the client trusting the server enough to establish a secure connection and you then authenticating across that connection using a client certificate.

Comment: so is it true that the only use of the client ssl options is to influence whether or not the client trusts the server's credentials? and that without them, it will simply accept whatever certificate is used? that without client ssl options, the client will even trust a self-signed certificate without question?

Comment: You are correct that the use of the client SSL options is to influence whether or not the client trusts the server (for example if you provided a certificate signed by a different CA then the connection would fail). Without the options the client would attempt to find the root certificate for the issuer (even if it is self signed) - we use self signed a lot in development but the certificate is still signed by the CA so it is accepted by the client. You can't use *any* certificate, it must be *trusted*.

Comment: I only understand what you were saying after I write my own answer (But I voted you up anyway.)

Answer (score -1):

SSL communication starts with a `handshake` phase, during which a `public-crypto-key` is being send to client for future use. So you don't have to have it, your client will get it anyway.

Then why do we need these `Public SSL certificate`?

`Public SSL certificate` does include `public-crypto-key` so you actually can compare the `public-crypto-key` coming from the server with `public-crypto-key` from your `Public SSL certificate`. This does not really make sense by itself unless you also want to check if this `public-crypto-key` was issued by some specific `Certificate Authority (CA)`.

Anyway, why do we need to check if this `public-crypto-key` was issued by some specific `Certificate Authority (CA)`? And you really don't care about it when you connect your MYSQL server to your DB client by IP. Because you know an IP of your MySQL server and you already do trust it.

`Certificate Authority (CA)` is a kind of `legacy` coming from another use of SSL secured protocols known `HTTPS`. In `HTTPS` you connect to unknown IP address, but there is one thing you should be sure about - `a domain name`. The domain names can be reassigned to a new IP addresses every minute. And it can be reassigned to your own localhost (via configuration of the 'hosts' file). Just imagines a sophisticated computer virus that comes to your computer, deploys a web server and reassign your "your-bank.com" web domain to that web server. Next time you open your browser, you enter your bank account credentials, but instead of giving you access to your bank account the web server sends your credentials to hackers. It would be upsetting, right? To avoid this scenario people invented `HTTPS`.

In HTTPS your browser doing some checks for you. It requires a `public-crypto-key` from a web server just to compare it with a list of known `Public SSL certificates` from trusted `Certificate Authority (CA)`. Then it checks the domain name assigned to this `Public SSL certificates` and establishes if this web server indeed allowed to serve content for the provided domain.

But then, why our "sophisticated virus" cannot parse a `handshake` and extract a `public-crypto-key` from the real web site just to give it to your browser?

The answer is - "it can". And it can allow `HTTPS` authorisation to pass, but then the fraudulent web server would need to "talk" to your browser. And to be able to  "talk" the fraudulent web server would need to use `private-crypto-key` to encrypt a server messages, but `private-crypto-key` is difficult to achieve.

See, we won.

The end.

Except for one thing, AWS uses domain names to access RDS, not the IP addresses. So we do need `Public SSL certificates`. But MySQL_Workbench is not a web browser so, you would think, it probably doesn't know much about `Certificate Authorities`. But in reality MySQL_Workbench does know about `Certificate Authority (CA)` and to activate it you need to go to "SSL" tab and set "Use SSL" drop down list to "Require and Verify CA" - in this case your would need to provide `your.pem` file to "SSL CA File:" field.

Back to your question: "why the client reports that the connection is SSL encrypted when I provided no certificate?"

Because it is encrypted with some certificate and it is up to your client to either go with the certificate provided by MySQL server or to verify CA and maybe reject it. Now you tell me, why have you setup your DB client to accept any certificates from the MySQL server bypassing the verification of CA?